# How can internationalized(translated) array's value of rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rubygems

This section is present in model, we use this for form submission.

```
GENDER_TYPES = %w[Male Female Other]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question here. Its a bit unclear.

Comment: I have a from where there is a field name gender. I use these array value for submitting the form. But I need to use translation on gender. Like in English it's OK to show [Male, female and other] but when the site is in Bangla it will show নারী পুরুষ and other.

Comment: You probably want to do this translation on the front end. Not on the model. Store it in whatever langauge (or integer enum) format you want in the db, and then translate before showing it to the user. How you translate it is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this works for you but what I do in this case is using a ([Rails enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.6/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)). In your model:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  enum gender: [:male, :female, :other]
end
```

My ApplicationRecord class:

```rb
   class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
     self.abstract_class = true

     def self.enum_t(enum_name, enum_value)
       I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.#{model_name.i18n_key}.#{enum_name.to_s.pluralize}.#{enum_value}")
     end
   end
```

In my en.yml:

```yaml
  en:
    activerecord:
      attributes:
        my_model:
          genders:
            male: Male
            female: Female
            other: Other
```

In my view to create a select:

```rb
f.select :gender, MyModel.genders.keys.collect { |gender| [MyModel.enum_t(:gender, gender), gender] }
```

Or show action:

```rb
= MyModel.enum_t(:gender, my_model.gender)
```